# Transparency background wrong on Dual-screen

Tags: 10.10, compiz, multiple-monitors, transparency

Using compiz with transparency behind windows and borders on a dual-screen system; all works fine, but the background that shows through with any transparency done by compiz is wrong.

It appears to be using the whole-width image from the display to generate the transparent image, but applying it to each display separately; so it's squished horizontally by 50%, and doesn't match the foreground.

Cripes this is hard to put into words... if anyone can tell me how to grab a screengrab I can paste it somewhere!

I'm an ubuntu veteran -- but new to ubuntu desktops!

(Display controller is ATI Technologies Inc Radeon X1650 Pro)

Answer (score 1):

Have found a russian website that google managed to kind-of translate, which seemed relevant.

Had instructions for updating radeon drivers from a third-party ppa - which I've tried and it seems to work so far... posting here in case anyone can cast any light - or knows who to report it to for fixing in next ubuntu release.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/radeon 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```